# What is a better way to model a treeNode?

Tags: f#, treenode

What are the pros and cons of each of the following two ways to create a tree node?

```
type TreeNode = | TreeNode of int * (TreeNode option) * (TreeNode option) * (TreeNode option)



type Node = | Node of int * Node * Node

        | None
```

Comment: This question would probably fit better on codereview.stackexchange.com .

Comment: Your `TreeNode` constructor has three children instead of two for `Node`.

Answer (score 3):

They are very close, but not entirely equivalent. You can actually reason about functional types quite nicely using mathematics (see for example [my recent article](http://tomasp.net/blog/types-and-math.aspx/)), but you can see that even informally.

Given any `TreeNode(num, optLeft, optRight)`, you can always create a `Node` containing the same information (`None` of the option type will be mapped to `Node.None`).

Interestingly, this does not work the other way round. If someone gives you `Node.None`, you cannot turn it into `TreeNode`, because `TreeNode` needs at least one integer in the root.

So, they are equivalent with the exception that the second one allows empty trees. From the practical perspective, the second type seems easier to use (because you only have to handle empty tree in one place).