# C# version of trees defined in F#

Tags: data-structures, tree, f#, c#-to-f#

In relation to this question: [What is a better way to model a treeNode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24412225/what-is-a-better-way-to-model-a-treenode)

I am thinking how to define similar trees in c# so that they would have the same difference.
So, having

```
type TreeNode = | TreeNode of int * (TreeNode option) * (TreeNode option) * (TreeNodeoption)

type Node = | Node of int * Node * Node
            | None
```

According to @Tomas Petricek answer, the difference between those two types is that the first one doesn't allow to create a truly empty tree. A TreeNode would always have a int value in it.

What is the way to express this in C#?

Comment: Float? Wouldn't it have an int?

Comment: Yes, You're right, i changed "float" to "int".

Comment: If you want you can express it just as the F# compiler handles it: with a base-class TreeNode/Node and subclasses for the cases (ok - only cases with data) - But C# has no good pattern matching so you gain almost nothing ... better look for thinks like Visitor-pattern etc. ... or just use F# ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really just a particular case of a Discriminated Union in C#. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3151702/discriminated-union-in-c-sharp) for a good discussion on that.

Comment: Well, i thought, that maybe there's some less verbose solution than implementing a union equivalent and then using it, but obviously, this is a good answer and it's the only one so far.